# Hide B in <x>A<br/>B</x>

Tags: jquery

I have a:

```
<h2>foo<br/>bar</h2>
```

and I'd like to hide "bar", but I can't figure out a proper selector.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 12):

I think you should wrap B in `<span>B</span>` and hide that span.

Answer (score 6):

First: the correct way is to add another tag, if you can, as the others suggested.
However, this can be done using jQuery's `contents()` selector, in two stages (I've googled on how to find text nodes with jQuery).
First, on `$(document).ready`, find all free text nodes and surround them with dummy `<span>`s (or whatever you want). Given, this will spam your DOM a little:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("h2").contents()
    .filter(function(){ return this.nodeType != 1; })
    .wrap("<span/>");
});
```

Now you don't have any naked text nodes, so you can easily select the second line:

```
$("h2 br").nextAll();
```

Answer (score 4):

An all css solution:

```
h2 {
    font-size:0%;
}
h2:first-line {
    font-size:19pt;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try h2:not(:first-line)

It's doubtful that this works though, first-line is rather buggy across browsers. (see http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/not#selector and http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pseudo_first-line.asp )

Comment: PPK has some more info about first-line as well - http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t18

Comment: Do you have tested? I tried this does not work. JQuery does not support: first-line

Comment: :first-line is a CSS pseudo-class, but jQuery didn't implement it. Maybe you can try an all-css solution, that's actually a good idea if it works cross-browser.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a selector for it as far as I know. A possible (hacky) solution would be to set a height for the H2 element and add overflow: hidden;

Answer (score 0):

It’s not possible to select a text node through a selector. However, you can still do what you want:

```
var brFound = false;
$('h2').contents().each(function() {
  if (brFound) {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    // Alternatively, you could use either of these, but it won’t be as fast:
    // $(this).remove();
    // $(this).wrap('<span style="display:none;" />');
  }
  if (this.tagName && this.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'br') {
    brFound = true;
  }
});
```

This will remove all text nodes and other elements that appear after a `<br>` inside an `<h2>` element, leaving the `<br>` intact.