# jQuery: Find the text of a list item that contains a nested ul

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
<ul id="list">
<li>item1
    <ul>
        <li>sub1</li>
        <li>sub2</li>
    </ul>    
</li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to respond to a li click event and use the text of the li elsewhere. However, if the click is on an li that contains a nested ul, I of course get the text of all elements.

```
$("#list li").click(function() {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

returns item1sub1sub2, as expected.

I can't figure out how to get just 'item1' if the item 1 li is clicked. I tried the following (among other things) with no luck:

```
$("#list li").click(function() {
    alert($(this).filter("ul").text());
});
```

Any ideas?

EDIT

This is a snippet of an example - it could be multiple levels deep. I also do not want to wrap the list item text in a span or other markup.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What about this approach? Clone the object, remove the clone's children and *then* find the text content.

```
$("#list li").click(function () {
    alert($(this).clone().children().remove().end().text());
}
```

Perhaps not the most efficient approach, but it's entirely intuitive, pretty tidy, and you don't have to muck with your html.

Comment: Thanks, this works well. I've selected this as the correct answer, but I may add a span around the text to make this a little bit cleaner in this case. Still a good tip for similar situations.

Answer (score 9):

Normal DOM methods allow to access text contents for just one element, rather than jquery:

```
$("#list li").click(function() {
    alert($(this)[0].firstChild.textContent)
});
```

firstChild in this case is the textNode beneath the li element

Comment: I prefer this approach as you can also use it to set the text, without losing any wrapped elements, unlike the other version.   (Out of scope of the question, I know, but I needed both.)

Answer (score 7):

you're having a hard time because `text()` does what it should - returns the text of this and all child elements. The easiest thing to do is to add another tag to every `<li>`, and use this tag.
For example:

```
<ul id="list">
<li><span>item1</span>
    <ul>
        <li><span>sub1</span></li>
        <li><span>sub2</span></li>
    </</ul>    
</li>
</ul>
```

And then you have a simple selector:

```
$("#list li").click(function() {
   alert($(this).find("span").eq(0).text());
});
```

or, if possilbe (depending on your style), you may add the event to the span:

```
$("#list span").click(function() {
   alert($(this).text());
});
```

If you cannot add these `<span>`s (as you say) you can use jQuery's `.contents()`
 to add them for you, similar to what was done here:

> [Hide B in <x>A<br/>B</x>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992472/hide-b-in-xabr-b-x/992568#992568)

Comment: Thank you for talking about `.contents()`, that helped me solve a similar problem!

Comment: Adding <span>s removes clickable blocks from list items

Answer (score 1):

This checks if the list item has any children and if so it filters out only the text nodes and concatenates the result (in this case it will work for text elements wherever they're put in the li). If you only ever want to check for elements at the start you can avoid the for loop and just work with this.firstChild

```
$("#list li").click(function(e) {
    if ($(this).children().length > 0) {
       var text = "";
       for (var i = 0; i < this.childNodes.length; i++) {
           var node = this.childNodes[i];
           if (node.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(node.nodeValue).length > 0) {
                text += $.trim(node.nodeValue);
           }
       }
       alert(text);
    }
    else {
       alert($(this).text());
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So this mechanism pulls out the html from the child element, replaces the newlines with nothing, and then returns the string only up to the first "`<`" character. I also added `event.stopPropagation` to avoid calling the click event bubbling up to the parent.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#list li").click(function(event) {
    var sourceHTML = $(this).html().replace(/\n/g,'').replace(/<.*/,'');
    alert(sourceHTML);
    event.stopPropagation();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the each method. so try the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('ul').each(function() {
            $(this).find('li').click(function() {
                var listItem = this;
                alert($(listItem).text());
            });
        })
    });
```

with the following markup

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hello. text() on an li element will still return the full text of all children. In fact, the each() is redundant here, it's the same as `$(ul li).click`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve same

```
$("#list li").click(function() {
    alert($(this).contents().not('ul,ol').text());
});
```