# Remove formatting except specific class

Tags: jquery, formatting

I'm trying to remove all html formatting inside a `<div>`, except for a specific class.

I tried

```
$('div#text :not(a.keep)').contents().each(function () {
    $(this).html($(this).text());
});
```

But it doesn't change anything to the content of the div.

sample input : `<span>a </span><span><a class="keep">b</a></span> c`

desired output : `a <a class="keep">b</a> c`

**WHY ?**

Why am I trying to do this ? I have a div, contenteditable, and I want to format what the user types. I have a timer, and every few seconds I check the contents of the div to find stuff to format, but I want to keep what has been marked to keep.

Comment: Are you trying to remove all the elements like <span>, <font>, etc or just the styles from these elements?

Comment: every element, mostly <span>s

Comment: You should be carfull because it will also remove the <a> link if any.

Comment: Oh never mind, that's why you have the a.keep class

Comment: What got me stuck is that a.keep could be wrapped by any number of tags I don't care about. I guess I need to go reccursive on this one.

Comment: perhaps adding a wildcart before not (`$('div#text *:not(.keep)')`) would help? how about some sample HTML code as well? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your `.keep` can be anywhere (deeply) in your element

Here's an alternative approach.
The idea is to get all elements that your `#text` contains and THEN, loop through each to see if it's matching your requirements.

Here's a sample

```
function getChildrenDeep(elem)
{
    var ret = [];

    $(elem).each(function(k,v){
        ret.push(v);
        if ($(v).children().length > 0) ret = $.merge(ret,getChildrenDeep($(v).children()));
    });

    return ret;
}
var plainChildren = getChildrenDeep($("#text")),
    final = '';

$(plainChildren).each(function(k,v){
    if (!$(v).hasClass("keep"))
        final += $(v).clone().children().remove().end().text(); /* See Reference */
    else
        final += $(v)[0].outerHTML;
});

document.write(final);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5hjnX/4/

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1023869/1607098)

Comment: That's odd. When I copy the fiddle the order of elements isn't kept.

Comment: If the html is "<span>a </span><span><a class="keep">b</a></span> c", I get "c a b" -> http://jsfiddle.net/5hjnX/5/

Answer (score 1):

you can use the not selector function.

```
$('div#text').not(a.keep).contents().each(function () {     
    $(this).html($(this).text()); 
});
```

however the call to `contents()` seems some what odd that will return text nodes as well as html nodes and seeing that you are trying to set the html property of every selected element that seems odd (there's no html to set on a text node)

if you wanted to take all the text of a node and replace any html in that node with only the text content then change to

```
$('div#text').not(a.keep).children().each(function () {     
    $(this).html($(this).text()); 
});
```

but if that's what you are trying to accomplish I would recommend

```
$('div#text').not(a.keep).children().each(function () {     
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).empty().html(text); 
});
```

because it's easier to see the intention. That does not solve the recursion problem if you can have `a.keep` nested in one of the selected elements