# hide only <li> value not its childrens

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery: Find the text of a list item that contains a nested ul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023199/jquery-find-the-text-of-a-list-item-that-contains-a-nested-ul)

```
<div id="pro">
<ol></ol>
<li id="4331">Region
      <ul>
         <li id="4332">Asia</li>
         <li id="6621">Europe</li>
      </ul>
</li>
</div>
```

If I Click on Region
only display Asia & Europe and Hide the Region when is clicked

i am using the .hide() method
here is what i did so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li").live("click", function(event) {
        $("li").hide(); 
        event.cancelBubble = true;
        loadChild($(this).attr("id"), event);
        return false;
    })
});
```

my current output is:

```
<div id="pro">
<li id="4331" style="display: none;">
Region
   <ul>
      <li id="4332">Asia</li>
      <li id="6621">Europe</li>
   </ul>
</li>
</div>
```

It hides everything...

but I want to hide only the parent Region 
I want to be able to click on it and after clicking  hide Region and show Asia And Europe only.

if possible to display both at different div like

click on Region its display in div 1 and there child on div 2

then also give the answer how it possible..

Please help me out with this
thanks.

Comment: The text `Region` is *also* a child of your `<li>`, except it is a text node, not an element.

Comment: You should not use `id` properties that start with a numeric.

Comment: Why not wrap `Region` in a `<span>` tag and hide that?

Answer (score 2):

You can't set an element to `display: none` (or its ilk) without affecting all children.  That's just the way it is.  It's still possible to psuedo-hide the "parent" content while having the child content display by setting the parent `font-size` to `0` and the childrens' `font-size` to some visible value:

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/MPCEa/

`event.cancelBubble = true;` can be replaced with `e.stopPropagation()`.

`$("li").hide();` in the context of the method should be `$(this).hide()`.  Otherwise, it will affect *all* `<li>`s in the document.

`.live` is dead.  Update your code to at least jQuery 1.7 and use `.on`.

Answer (score 0):

you cant really hide it but you can delete it by grabbing the text node and delete it.

```
$("li#4331").contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
}).remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TLpk9/6/

Comment: as your answer its work but i how huge list of parent and there child how to use your answer to click any where this got hide...

Answer (score 0):

If you could wrap "Region" with `<span>` tag, you can have better control.