# How do I wrap each text item in a tag with another tag, like p

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, before you ask why, the idea is to find the position of the text on the screen, the only way I've found to do that is it's an actual element.

```
$('button#orphan').click(function(){

    //The vars are defined globally for debugging.

    pNodeSplitText = new Array();
    pNodes=$('p');
    orphanedNodes=new Array();
    pNodes.each(function(index){
        pNodesHTMLbefore=pNodes.eq(index).html(); //May not be nessicary
        pNodeSplitText[index] = pNodes.eq(index).text().split(' '); //To get each text item
        pNodeSplitText.each(function(i){
          // this is where i will wrap each wrord, but how?
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: What is the question/problem?

Comment: can you share a sample of the html and the desired output

Comment: I *think* you want something similar to this: [How to select nth line of text (CSS/JS)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966441/how-to-select-nth-line-of-text-css-js)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any `HTML` but if it's just like given (in the example here) `HTML` then you may try something like this ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/953dp/2/))

**HTML:**

```
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Some more text</p>
```

**JS:**

```
$('button#orphan').click(function(){
    var pNodeSplitText = [], orphanedNodes = [], pNodes = $('p');
    pNodes.each(function(i){
        pNodeSplitText = pNodes.eq(i).text().split(' ');
        var newText = '<span class="txt">' + pNodeSplitText.join('</span> <span class="txt">') + '</span>';
        $(pNodes[i]).html(newText);
    });
});
```