# target 2nd line of paragraph using pseudo class

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

```css
p::first-line{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
```

this css selector target only first line what if i want to target 2nd  or third line and change its color

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select nth line of text (CSS/JS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966441/how-to-select-nth-line-of-text-css-js)

Comment: This can't be done without JavaScript.