# Setting border on first element per line

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

(I'm quite new in web-design) I have a list of links (sections on current page) that can extend to multiple lines depending on viewport size. Links are separated by a vertical line (border-left):

[image: Current results]

I want to avoid the border to be displayed for first element of each line. I've managed to avoid it for the the first child but I can't figure out how to do it for the first element of each line. Something like:

[image: Expected results]

Note that this list is probably different for each page.

**Question**: How to achieve such effect? CSS? JavaScript?

```css
.links a {
  display: inline-block;
}
.links a:not(:first-child) {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.links a:not(:last-child) {
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
  <a href="#">Link number 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link number 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link number 3</a>
  <a href="#">Link number 4</a>
  <a href="#">Link number 567</a>
  <a href="#">Link number 6</a>
  <a href="#">Link number 7</a>
  <a href="#">Link number 8</a>
  <a href="#">Link number 9</a>
</div>
```

PS: the `display: inline-block` is just to avoid wrapping between lines. I'd like to avoid changing the HTML structure since many pages are affected. Such links are always nested in a `<div class="links"></div>` as shown in the example.

Comment: You would need media queries. There is no way to do this dynamically with CSS. It has no idea when items wrap.

Comment: Oh... so, what if pages have different set of links? one specific CSS for each one? I'll update the question to be clear about it... may be some JS?

Comment: That would probably be the only way.

Comment: Your dynamic list is a list of words, so only way I imagine as *the best* from performance perspective is to get an avarage widht of a symbol (number, letter) and calculate `@media queries` in CSS on those sizes

Comment: @Paulie_D *"There is no way to do this dynamically with CSS."* while the "dynamically" portion holds true, OP's specific request is possible with CSS only. Though my answer could be considered a workaround, I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `overflow: hidden;` on the container and give your links a negative `left-margin`. You can counteract the negative margin on the other links by simply doubling the `padding-right`.

```css
.links {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.links a {
  display: inline-block;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
.links a:not(:last-child) {
  padding-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
  <a href="#">Link number 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link number 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link number 3</a>
  <a href="#">Link number 4</a>
  <a href="#">Link number 567</a>
  <a href="#">Link number 6</a>
  <a href="#">Link number 7</a>
  <a href="#">Link number 8</a>
  <a href="#">Link number 9</a>
</div>
```

---

**How It Works**

The left margin and left border *are* present, however the negative margin forces them out of the container. We then hide anything outside of the container with `overflow: hidden`.

The example below presents what's actually happening by removing `overflow: hidden;` and giving the container a border:

```css
.links {
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: visible;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
.links a {
  display: inline-block;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
.links a:not(:last-child) {
  padding-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
  <a href="#">Link number 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link number 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link number 3</a>
  <a href="#">Link number 4</a>
  <a href="#">Link number 567</a>
  <a href="#">Link number 6</a>
  <a href="#">Link number 7</a>
  <a href="#">Link number 8</a>
  <a href="#">Link number 9</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! it works flawlessly! Could it be modified to work when `.links` has `text-align: center`? It is a change in the design for a subset of pages... should I post it as a separate question or extend this one?

Comment: I managed to solve that particular issue using JS, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy way where you can use a pseudo element to hide the first borders.

```css
.links {
  overflow: hidden;
  position:relative;
  width:600px;
  animation:change 4s linear infinite alternate;
}
.links:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:1px;
  background:#fff;
}
.links a {
  display: inline-block;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

@keyframes change {
  to{width:160px}
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
  <a href="#">Link number 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link number 2 5q4d </a>
  <a href="#">Link number 3</a>
  <a href="#">Link number 4</a>
  <a href="#">Link number 567</a>
  <a href="#">Link number 6</a>
  <a href="#">Link number 7 dqsd dqs</a>
  <a href="#">Link number 8</a>
  <a href="#">Link number 9</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I prefer the solutions proposed by [Tyler Roper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52595438/1485885) and [Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52598912/1485885) because they show the correct result from the very first rendering (especially noticeable in pages with many additional resources), I want to share another solution (using JavaScript) inspired in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1966633/1485885).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  fn = function() {
    var prevTop = -1;
    $("a", $(".links")).each(function() {
      var link = $(this);
      var top = link.offset().top;
      if (top == prevTop) {
        link.attr("class", "border");
      } else { // new line
        prevTop = top;
        link.removeClass("border"); // in case 'border' was previously added
      }
    });
  };
  $(window).resize(fn);
  fn();
});
```

```css
.links {
  text-align: center;
}

.links a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.links a.border {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="links">
  <a href="#">Link number 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link number 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link number 3</a>
  <a href="#">Link number 4</a>
  <a href="#">Link number 567</a>
  <a href="#">Link number 6</a>
  <a href="#">Link number 7</a>
  <a href="#">Link number 8</a>
  <a href="#">Link number 90</a>
</div>
```

As seen, above code manages the case where the links are centered in the screen instead of left-aligned.

*Note: As text-centering was not part of my original question (such requirement appeared after I implemented the accepted answer), I'm not considering that for the correctness of the other answers proposed, I'm just publishing this contribution for completeness.*