# get first few lines in td tag with css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I've been facing such a challenge for the first time. I have a table with simple  tags and text inside. What I want to do is to give ALL first lines of  tag font weight bold. I came up with a solution `td::ntf-line(-n+2)` (where 2 is a number of lines) but it didn't work. Did anyone face the same thing before? Thanks in advance. Example of a code:

```
<tr>
            <td>10:30 AM</td>
            <td rowspan="2" class="web">Web Design<br> Fundamentals<br>MULT1083<br>B.Ryan / A3102</td>
            <td rowspan="4" class="networks">Introduction to<br> Networks<br>NCRC1157<br>F.Bekkering<br>A-3102</td>
            <td rowspan="4" class="hardwareLab">Introduction to<br> Hardware<br>LAB<br>CEIO1048<br>C.Pieroni<br>A3012</td>
            <td rowspan="4" class="microsoftLab">Microsoft Client OS<br>LAB<br>OSSE1060<br>J.Jakson<br>A-3105</td>
        </tr>
```

so I want to make `Web Design<br> Fundamentals` font weight bold as well as for all others . Only CSS solutions please, as all of you I'm too lazy to write `<b>` tag everywhere

Comment: Can you give an example of what you tried and why it didn't work?

Comment: try `td::first-line{font-weight:bold}`

Comment: @SooriyaDasanayake First-line works just for the first line and I need first TWO lines =) this is the challenging part

Comment: @user1178830 I want to make first TWO lines of text in every TD element bold

Comment: you can use <b> tag for specific words.. eg: `<b>Web Design</b>`

Comment: @SooriyaDasanayake in my description I've mentioned that I don't want to use <b> because the table is huuuge and it will take me hours. The process needs to be automatic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select nth line of text (CSS/JS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966441/how-to-select-nth-line-of-text-css-js)

Answer (score 0):

here u can use css tag span dear

```
css:
.sampl{
  font-weight:bold;
 }

html:
 <tr>
        <td>10:30 AM</td>
        <td rowspan="2" class="web">Web Design<br><span class="sampl"> Fundamentals</span><br>MULT1083<br>B.Ryan / A3102</td>
        <td rowspan="4" class="networks">Introduction to<br> Networks<br>NCRC1157<br><span class="sampl">F.Bekkering</span><br>A-3102</td>
        <td rowspan="4" class="hardwareLab">Introduction to<br> <span class="sampl">Hardware </span><br>LAB<br>CEIO1048<br>C.Pieroni<br>A3012</td>
        <td rowspan="4" class="microsoftLab">Microsoft Client OS<br>LAB<br>OSSE1060<br>J.Jakson<br>A-3105</td>
    </tr>
```

like this u need to use class every where u want to bold the text.

Comment: too long, previously I've explained that the code is way too big to add some extra markup over it, so I'm looking for a pseudo class solution or some CSS trick.