# Does jQuery support p:nth-line()?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I have a dynamic text (like product description) and I am storing it under paragraph tag, so here I need to change the background color of the specific line as per operator input like 2nd line must be in #000 color or 8th line must be in #eee color and so on. So, does jQuery support p:nth-line() like CSS? If is there another method to do that, please share.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966441/how-to-select-nth-line-of-text-css-js.

Comment: Thanks for sharing!

Comment: You are welcome!