# How to make every second line text in a different color if no break element?

Tags: html, css

I have plain text in my div class. Every few words in my text start from a new line but I don't have any HTML marked breaks.

I need every second line in my text to have different colors, for example: red, black, red, black... Tried everything `nth-child`, nothing works.

Just `:first-line` pseudo-element makes the first line in a different color, but this type of pseudo-element only exists for the first line.

Example:

```css
.text {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">Hello world my name is Thomas</div>
```

Comment: You might want to look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59331440/17175441

Comment: God bless you Sir! Some tweaks and it worked!