# Styling every nth line of a paragraph with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How can I style every nth line of a paragraph with css **without** manually adding linebreaks or inserting tags so that the line-breaking is still defined by the width of the container? Is there something similar to `:nth-of-type` but for lines in a paragraph?

### Example:

I would like to style this:

```html
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
<p>
```

like this:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur

**sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod**

tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna

**aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.**

(And the linebreaks should be defined by the width of the container.)

### My Idea:

```css
p:nth-line(2n) {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: No this is not possible with CSS.

Comment: CSS won't allow to do it, there is only a `::first-line` attribute. You can check this answer using Javascript, result is working: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1966633/999617

Comment: @VincentDecaux perfect, thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select nth line of text (CSS/JS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966441/how-to-select-nth-line-of-text-css-js)